# Xamarin - Picker Selected Item not changing

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, picker

I am trying to bind a Picker in Xamarin.

My HTML Code

```
<Picker Title="Select a coin"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Coins}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Short_Name}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCoin,Mode=TwoWay}" />

   <Label Text="{Binding SelectedCoin.Short_Name}" /> //This does not 
   change when I change the item in the picker.
```

Here is my code In the ViewModel

```
    public class Currency
    {
        public string Short_Name { get; set; }
        public string Image_Url { get; set; }
    }

    Currency selectedCoin;
    public ObservableCollection<Currency> _coins = new 
    ObservableCollection<Currency>();

    public Currency SelectedCoin
    {
        get { return selectedCoin; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedCoin != value)
            {
                selectedCoin = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CryptoCurrency> Coins
    {
        get
        {
            return _coins;
        }
        set
        {
            SetObservableProperty(ref _coins, value);
        }
    }

    public async void GetCoins()
    {
        Currency c = new Currency();
        coinsPageModel.Coins = await coinsPageModel.GetCoins();

        foreach (var item in coinsPageModel.Coins)
        {
            c.Short_Name = item.Short_Name;
            Coins.Add(c);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I have tried several different ways and I just cannot seem to change the text in the label below the picker when I change the picker item. Any help or help is much appreciated!

Comment: I think in  `OnPropertyChanged();` you need to pass property name. Like `OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCoin");`

Comment: I tried this but no luck. Also, the label defaults to the last list item initially and not the selectedCoin item.

Comment: Did you try RaisePropertyChanged for Short_Name and checked? Also you need to implement the PropertyChanged virtual method in the Currency class

Answer (score 0):

You should raise the property change every time SelectedItem change, like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Currency> _coins = new ObservableCollection<Currency>();
public ObservableCollection<CryptoCurrency> Coins
{
    get
    {
        return _coins;
    }
    set
    {
        SetObservableProperty(ref _coins, value);
    }
}

private Currency selectedCoin;
public Currency SelectedCoin
{
    get { return selectedCoin; }
    set
    {
        if (selectedCoin != value)
        {
            selectedCoin = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedCoin);
        }
    }
}
```

Your XAML seems correct.

Comment: It says RaisePropertyChanged does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It was a mistake from my end, "Currency c = new Currency();" should be inside the foreach loop. This was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Currency c = new Currency();
Inside of GetCoins, should be placed inside the foreach loop.